# Connection refused to Postgresql on docker

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect to postgres docker container via psycopg2, but i keep getting the same error.

I'm doing this on jupyter (docker container), i restart several times postgres container and i change **postgresql.config** `listen_addresses = '*'`  to `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` and it's the same error.

This is the docker run command:

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx -d -p 5432:5432 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres
```

python

```
import psycopg2 as pg
connection = pg.connect("host=localhost dbname=easy_cleaning user=root")
```

I expect to connect, but i got this error:

```
----> 3 connection = pg.connect("host=localhost dbname=easy_cleaning user=root")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    124 
    125     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 126     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    127     if cursor_factory is not None:
    128         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: It would help if you shared the docker run command that you're using, or the docker-compose file. This is most likely a problem with the port mapping on the container.

Comment: I updated it up there

Comment: try to connect with the host's IP. Type `docker inspect postgres` (where postgres is the container name) and find the `IPAddress`. Otherwise, you can use docker-compose and use the service name as the host (but keep in mind that the API and the database should be on the same network)

Comment: Thanks that was it, now is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your configuration, your container is not on localhost, Docker created a private IP to it. So you need to run:

```
docker inspect postgres
```

And look for *IPAddress* field to use in your connection as:

```
connection = pg.connect("host=<DOCKER_IP_ADDRESS> dbname=easy_cleaning user=root")
```

**OR**

You can use docker-compose to run your images as *services* and each service has it's name, which can be used as a hostname in your connections, like:

```
connection = pg.connect("host=postgres dbname=easy_cleaning user=root")
```

Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)